# cookie not passing to page

Tags: php, javascript, cookies

hello i am trying to pass a cookie from one page to another, and its just not working for some reason

i set the cookie in php.

Page a:

```
   <?php $cc= 'testcookie';
    setcookie("cc", $video, time()+36000);
     ?>
```

and i try to read the cookie in JS.

Page b:

```
function readCookie(name) {  

var cookiename = name + '=';  

var ca = document.cookie.split(';');  

for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++)  
{  

    var c = ca[i];  

    while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);  

    if (c.indexOf(cookiename) == 0) return c.substring(cookiename.length,c.length);  

}  

return null;  
}
```

and i always get null...

when i try to set the cookie in the same page that i try to read it, it works...

any ideas?

Comment: Can you read a cookie called "cc"?  Because it sure looks to me as if that's the cookie you're setting.

Comment: haha its not called cc i changed the name coz its long and annoying to look at the really cookie name is "recent_uploaded_videos_to_v-teacher"

Comment: Well, the point is that your "setcookie()" call is not referencing the variable; you're passing a string constant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try `setcookie("cc", $video, time()+36000, "/", "example.com");` to specify the domain and the path. `"/"` mean full domain. And sometimes there may occur some problems with cookies if try to use them on the http://localhost/ .

Comment: thank you that worked really well. how would i do the same using JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

There's also a plugin for Firebug, which you can use to easily see what cookies have been set per domain.  I believe it's called FireCookie.